# Why isn't myInterval being cleared?

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

```js
const homeButton = document.getElementById('home');
window.myInterval = 0;


const showHome = () => {
  console.log('showHome');
  window.myInterval = setInterval(wait, 400)
}

const wait = () => {
  console.log('wait');
  if (homeButton.style.visibility === 'visible') {
    console.log('clearingInterval');
    window.myInterval = clearInterval(myInterval)
  }
  window.myInterval = clearInterval(myInterval)
  homeButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

const waitUntil = () => {
  console.log('waitUntil');
  homeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  window.myInterval = clearInterval(myInterval)
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 2%;
  height: 80vh;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
  color: rgb(245, 241, 241);
  border: solid 2px rgb(243, 243, 243);
}

#home {
  visibility: hidden;
}

div:hover {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 252, 252);
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  width: 92%;
  bottom: 4%;
  height: 95%;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 252, 252);
  color: rgb(255, 252, 252);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div onmouseover="showHome()">
    <button id="home" onclick="">Home</button>
  </div>
  <button id="right" onmouseover="waitUntil()">test</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So basically, if you keep on hovering over the home button div, it will glitch and just keep the home button visible, this is because in the console you can see 'wait' being spammed and so that means that the interval is going forever and I'm not sure why, I tried to get it to clear but it doesn't?

```
  if (homeButton.style.visibility === 'visible') {
    console.log('clearingInterval');
    window.myInterval = clearInterval(myInterval)
  }
  window.myInterval = clearInterval(myInterval)
```

Is where I'm trying to clear the interval.

Want to see the full page? https://fluid-ui.danialstudent.repl.co/

Press F12 on that page and then hover over the sidebar and you can see 'wait' and after 'clearingInterval' repeating a lot.

I noticed that waitUntil function makes it invisible but then it goes back because of the interval

Comment: Have you tried: `clearInterval(window.myInterval)`?

Comment: @imvain2 Yes, just tried it and it didn't work out

Comment: Could you tell us for what design purposes are you clearing the interval?

Comment: @iolibitz So it will show the home button when the sidebar is hovered over and hide the home button when it's not hovered over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by other answers, you can simply call `clearInterval(myInterval)` without assignment. However, if your design goal is to show the home button only when its parent div is hovered upon, then you can use a function that hides the home button upon `mouseleave` instead of setting intervals.

```js
const homeButton = document.getElementById('home');

const showHome = () => {
  console.log('showHome');
  homeButton.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function unshowHome() {
  console.log('clear!');
  homeButton.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 2%;
  height: 80vh;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
  color: rgb(245, 241, 241);
  border: solid 2px rgb(243, 243, 243);
}
#home {
  visibility: hidden;
}
div:hover {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 252, 252);
}
#right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  width: 92%;
  bottom: 4%;
  height: 95%;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 252, 252);
  color: rgb(255, 252, 252);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div onmouseenter="showHome()" onmouseleave="unshowHome()">
    <button id="home" onclick="">Home</button>
    </div>
    <button id="right" onmouseover="">test</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To answer your original question, the interval is not cleared because the same variable `window.myInterval` is used for multiple intervals. When the sidebar is hovered upon twice within 400ms, a new interval is assigned to the variable before the first interval can be cleared. This causes subsequent `clearInterval()` to clear only the second interval, while reference to the first interval is lost. You can see how the following code clears intervals twice but the first interval continues to run.

```js
window.myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("interval 1");
}, 1000);

window.myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("interval 2");
}, 1000);

clearInterval(window.myInterval);
clearInterval(window.myInterval);  // undefined
```

Comment: I tried but the problem is the interval runs forever? I tried clearInterval(myInterval)

Comment: earingInterval
wait
clearingInterval
wait
clearingInterval
wait
clearingInterval
wait
clearingInterval
wait
clearingInterval
wait
clearingInterval
wait
clearingInterval
waitUntil
showHome
wait
wait
clearingInterval
showHome
wait
clearingInterval is what it's saying

Comment: I edited my answer. The interval runs forever because there's a chance that two intervals can be triggered within 400ms, in which case the second interval never gets cleared

Comment: Thanks so much! I wonder why there is no time.sleep like in python or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to redefine `window.myInterval`
just use `clearInterval(myInterval)` and it should end the loop

edit: if that doesn't work, try `clearInterval(window.myInterval)` incase the interval isn't declared globally

Comment: https://repl.it/@DanialStudent/Fluid-UI#script.js i tried it here